# wbkgd does not set background color

Tags: rust, ncurses

I'm using Rust to write an ncurses app.

I'm trying to set the color of a subwin, however having no success. I'm not even sure the window is created in the first place, or it just doesn't want to set the color.

Here's a minimal example:

```
use ncurses::*;

fn main() {
    setlocale(LcCategory::all, "");
    initscr();
    keypad(stdscr(), true);
    start_color();
    init_pair(1, COLOR_RED, COLOR_RED);
    loop {
        let user_input = get_wch();
        match user_input.unwrap() {
            WchResult::Char(ch) => {
                match ch {
                    27 => break,
                    _ => {}
                }
            },
            WchResult::KeyCode(code) => {
                match code {
                    KEY_F5 => {
                        let ln = subwin(stdscr(), LINES(), 5, 0, 0);
                        wbkgd(ln, COLOR_PAIR(1));
                        refresh();
                    },
                    _ => {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
    endwin();
}
```

As you can see, I initialized a color pair and invoked start_colors().

What could be the issue?

Comment: Curiously, it works if you move it out of the loop…

Comment: Seems like `wrefresh(ln)` makes it work.

Answer (score 0):

In this chunk

```
                    let ln = subwin(stdscr(), LINES(), 5, 0, 0);
                    wbkgd(ln, COLOR_PAIR(1));
                    refresh();
```

the `refresh` overwrites the result from the `subwin`.  Also, you would get better results by *OR*ing the `COLOR_PAIR` with a space (see [this](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-ncurses/2020-03/msg00016.html)).

Addressing the comments:

```
let user_input = get_wch();
```

also does a `refresh` (overwriting the result from the `subwin`).

Comment: I tried removing refresh() call, however nothing happens still. I also tried to OR a space with the color pair, it says it's not implemented.

Comment: Removing the `refresh` doesn't fix the issue. Moreover, moving this chunk before the loop works, even though the `refresh` is present.

Comment: I need this in the loop.

Comment: @dedmauz69 I suspected you need this in the loop, but the fact that it works outside the loop shows that `refresh` can't be the problem.

Comment: However the `refresh` doesn't seem to affect the result one way or the other: it works outside the loop with or without `refresh` and it doesn't work inside the loop with or without `refresh`.

Comment: Yeah, the problem lies elsewhere. I first tried it without refresh, then added it after it didn't work out. It still wouldn't work. I'm not sure what's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that your not refreshing the sub-window.  Try using wrefresh(ln) instead.  Actually use both refresh and refresh(ln).